# Is there a way to perform agglomerative clustering in batches in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, scalability

I have several groups of data, with row counts ranging up to 24,000. I have manually calculated pairwise distances between the points, where the distance is based on custom text-matching rules.

I have been able to perform agglomerative clustering using `hclust` on groups of size ~1000, but my system's resources cannot handle the 24K *x* 24K / 2 comparison needed for the larger groups.

The representation of the distances takes up O[n^2] space, but the clustering representation should only take up O(n*ln(n)) space. Are there any packages in R that can perform agglomerative clustering in batches for large amounts of data?

Comment: What do you mean by "in batches"?  Heirarchical clustering is a bottom up approach, so every iteration depends on the results of the previous iteration.

Comment: Information can be stored and queried though if you cannot load all of the information into memory at once, though. Using batches is a way of only loading a certain amount of data at a time to perform the calculations needed. It would increase the amount of time, but drastically reduce the amount of space needed.

Comment: Try other tools. For example I think ELKI can do single-link hierarchical with just O(n) memory.

Comment: I will look into that, although I prefer using average distance as opposed to single/complete linkage, as there are many ties and close values within large subnetworks of the data. My application might accidentally fall into a "rich get richer" type scenario, where unnecessarily large clusters form by connecting one leaf to a large cluster at a time.